# IdentityServer 4 Intermittently Returning Error returned from introspection endpoint causing 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer4 in Production and are intermittently getting "Error returned from introspection endpoint: An error occurred while sending the request.". This in turn is causing a 401 to be returned from the MVC Client and from our Web API.

The logs are set to debug level but are not showing any reason as to why the Introspection EndPoint is failing. What we do get in the logs in the MVC Client is

```
2018-03-01 10:41:54.405 +00:00 [ERR] Error returned from introspection endpoint: An error occurred while sending the request.
2018-03-01 10:41:54.406 +00:00 [INF] BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationIntrospection was not authenticated. Failure message: Error returned from introspection endpoint: An error occurred while sending the request.
2018-03-01 10:41:54.406 +00:00 [INF] Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: Error returned from introspection endpoint: An error occurred while sending the request.
2018-03-01 10:41:54.406 +00:00 [INF] Authorization failed for user: null.
```

The setup is ASP.Net Core hosted in IIS 8.5

- IdentityServer reference tokens using AspCoreIdentity over https
- AspCore MVC Application/Web API over https
- AspCore Web API over https

**IdentityServer**

The IdentityServer config is as follows (we set the access token to 1 day)

```
new Client
{
   ClientId = "Redacted",
   ClientName = "Redacted",
   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
   AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
   AccessTokenLifetime = 86400,

   RequireConsent = false,
   AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

   ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
   {
       new Secret("Redacted")
   },

   RedirectUris = new List<string>
   {
       $"{client}/signin-oidc"
   },
   PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
   {
       $"{client}/signout-callback-oidc"
   },                 

   AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
   {
       client
   },

   AllowedScopes = new List<string>
   {
       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
       "roles",
       "MonitoringInternalAPI",
       "MonitoringAPI",                        
       "MonitoringDialOutAPI",
       "MonitoringAdminAPI"
   },
   UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
   AllowOfflineAccess = true
}
```

The setup for IdentityServer

```
services.AddIdentityServer()                    
    .AddSigningCredential(Configuration["IdentityServer:X509Thumbprint"], 
                          StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
                          NameType.Thumbprint)         
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())                
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:Client"), Configuration.GetValue<int>("IdentityServer:AccessTokenLifetime")))
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

**MVC Application**

The MVC Application uses cookies for the Razor Views and bearer token for the in built API Calls. Also we use the MemoryCacheTicketStore implementation to store the roles.

The IdentityServer Setup

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {                    
                options.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerClient:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "Redacted";
                options.ClientSecret = "Redacted";

                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("MonitoringInternalAPI");
                options.Scope.Add("MonitoringAPI");
                options.Scope.Add("MonitoringDialOutAPI");
                options.Scope.Add("MonitoringAdminAPI");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.Scope.Add("roles");

                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnUserInformationReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        ClaimsIdentity claimsId = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                        var roles = context.User.Children().FirstOrDefault(j => j.Path == JwtClaimTypes.Role).Values().ToList();
                        claimsId.AddClaims(roles.Select(r => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, r.Value<String>())));

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
                };
            })
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerClient:Authority"];
                options.EnableCaching = true;
                options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);

                options.ApiName = "MonitoringInternalAPI";
                options.ApiSecret = "Redacted";

                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            });
```

**Web API**

The Identity Server setup is

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServer:Authority"];                   

                options.ApiName = "MonitoringAPI";
                options.RoleClaimType = "role";
                options.ApiSecret = "Redacted";
                options.EnableCaching = true;
                options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);

                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
```

Comment: I'm actually get the same exact intermittent error, were you able to figure out what was causing the issue?

Comment: Hi, in short no it is still happening. However after posting on the IdentityServer4 Gitter I got a response from somebody saying that it is more than likely the server that is struggling with the number of request. I'm inclined to believe this due to the way ASP.NET Core is hosted in IIS because it is only acting as a reverse proxy for Kestrel which means there are a lot more HTTP Requests/Responses.

Comment: We've been running ASP.NET Core 2.2 In-Process for around 2 weeks now and the issue seems to have been resolved. Therefore it definitely looks like it was the reverse proxy causing our server to struggle with the number of HTTP Requests/Responses